# What's the difference between [answers] and [answering-questions]?

Tags: discussion, meta-tags

^^ as the title.

Here in Meta.SuperUser, we have [answers](/questions/tagged/answers) and [answering-questions](/questions/tagged/answering-questions).

I'm not sure what's the difference between [answers](/questions/tagged/answers) and [answering-questions](/questions/tagged/answering-questions), because [answering-questions](/questions/tagged/answering-questions) is already included in the scope of [answers](/questions/tagged/answers).

What's the difference? **Should we merge** [answering-questions](/questions/tagged/answering-questions) to [answers](/questions/tagged/answers) ?

Comment: To me "answering questions" would be specifically about what to do when answering questions. How you address the question specifically. An "answer" is simply about the answer itself without the question. Seems to me that it is about where the focus of the meta question is. Is it specifically about the answer or about an answer to a question... It is a bit vague and fuzzy though.

Answer (score 5):

One of these is a verb-phrase, a process, while the other is a noun, a specific thing: Therefore, they are distinct.

There may be some overlap, as the process [answering-questions](/questions/tagged/answering-questions) results in the specific thing [answers](/questions/tagged/answers), but the process is not the thing itself, merely the cumulative actions by which the thing comes about, these are different tags, have their unique places, and should both be kept.

Comment: A good observation. Is this distinction obvious enough to be useful in practice? I feel like it might be easy for these tags to be confused and questions to not be tagged consistently.

Comment: There is likely to always be confusion regarding this. The community may decide it's simpler to embrace the confusion and merge the tags. I believe that for those who care, keeping them separate will be a helpful distinction.

Comment: Perhaps suitable text in the tags' wikis is all that's required.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator This is odd then, because the tag wiki for "answers" says: "Anything related to posting answers, e.g. about improving their content, voting on answers, editing others' answers, etc.", which seems like what answering-questions would be.